# Sybase sysobjects - what's the equivalent table in DB2?

Tags: sql, db2, sybase

I have a simple sql in Sybase,

```
select user_name(uid), type, name
  from sysobjects
```

I'm wondering that what is the equivalent sql in DB2?

Answer (score 5):

I don't think there is a single view that shows **all** objects.

For tables that would be `SYSCAT.TABLES`

All available views are listed in the manual: [Catalog Views](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc%2Fdoc%2Fr0008443.html)